# Interactable actors should be implemented via components or inheritances?

Tags: c++, software-engineering, unreal, component-based, inheritance

I am new to game development and I am learning Unreal Engine right now.

When a player character `APlayer` wants to interact with other actors (such as `ALight`, etc), generally the process is as follows:

- `APlayer` gets a reference to `ALight` via line tracing or collision.
- `APlayer` checks whether the reference is of type `ALight`, if yes then invoke the public `Interact` method exposed by `ALight`.

It is clear enough to me that I need to provide an interface (abstract class) first.

```cpp
class UInteractableInterface : public UInterface{};
class IInteractableInterface
{
public:
    virtual void Interact(AActor* Instigator) = 0;
};
```

Now for the `ALight` part I got confused in determining whether

- option A: `ALight` implements `IInteractableInterface`
- option B: `ALight` does not implement `IInteractableInterface` but it depends on `USwitch` which implements `IInteractableInterface`.

### Option A (`ALight` implementing `IInteractableInterface`)

```cpp
class ALight: public AStaticMeshActor, public IInteractableInterface
{
public:
    virtual void Interact(AActor* Instigator) override;
};


void ALight::Interact(AActor* Instigator)
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%hs"), __FUNCTION__);    
}
```

```cpp
void APlayer::InteractWithOther()
{
    // Other code pertaining to line tracing or collision
    // is removed for the sake of simplicity!

    AActor* OtherActor = Result.GetActor();    
    if(OtherActor && OtherActor->Implements<UInteractableInterface>()) 
    {
        auto InteractableActor = Cast<IInteractableInterface>(OtherActor);
        InteractableActor->Interact(this);
    }    
}
```

### Option B (`USwitch` implementing `IInteractableInterface`)

```cpp
class USwitch : public UActorComponent, public IInteractableInterface
{
public:
    virtual void Interact(AActor* Instigator) override;
};

void USwitch::Interact(AActor* Instigator)
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("%hs"), __FUNCTION__);    
}
```

```cpp
class ALight: public AStaticMeshActor
{
public:
    ALight();

protected: 
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere)
    class USwitch* Switch;
};

void ALight::ALight()
{
    Switch = CreateDefaultSubobject<USwitch>("Switch");
}
```

```cpp
void APlayer::InteractWithOther()
{
    // Other code pertaining to line tracing or collision
    // is removed for the sake of simplicity!

    if(AActor* OtherActor = Result.GetActor())
    {
        for (auto Comp : OtherActor->GetComponents())
        {
            if (Comp && Comp->Implements<IInteractableInterface>()) 
            {
                auto InteractableComp = Cast<IInteractableInterface>(Comp);
                InteractableComp->Interact(this);

                break; // for single retrieval 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Question

When developing with Unreal Engine, which approach is recommended and what are the prons and cons between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inheritance is typically faster than component based interactions.

The difference is one less run-time dereference.

The general rule is to use components for run-time and level-design time flexibility, otherwise use fixed(compiled) structures/objects.

Option A seems to provide the much more direct route.

By utilizing unique collision channels the `OtherActor->Implements<UInteractableInterface>()` check could be eliminated all together.

Comment: I just realized a scenario in which an actor has multiple interactable parts. For example, an enemy robot. Shooting at his head and shooting at his body must behave differently. So implementing interactable interface in component basis is mandatory I think.

Answer (score 1):

There is another option, make all Actors implement the IInteractableInterface interface by default (and remove that interface from the hierarchy) and use a `CanBeInteractedWith` query to check whether it's something that can be interacted with (or setting the proper collision channel).

This will simplify your code because you can assume all entity classes can be interacted with so no casts are needed and attempting to interact with something that doesn't have an interaction will result in a noop.

````
void APlayer::InteractWithOther()
{
    // Other code pertaining to line tracing or collision
    // is removed for the sake of simplicity!

    AActor* OtherActor = Result.GetActor();    
    if(OtherActor && OtherActor->CanBeInteractedWith()) 
    {
        OtherActor->Interact(this);//Other actor will handle the specific interaction, perhaps through checking all its components
    }    
}
```
````

Comment: But `CanBeInteractedWith()` does not exist in `AActor` class. How can `OtherActor` invokes it?

Comment: Both `Interact` and `CanBeInteractedWith` should be added to your base `AActor`. Instead of separate interfaces the idea is that the base Actor class implements all interfaces with noops and has queries to check whether it actually does something.

Comment: I think casting cannot be avoided. `Result.GetActor()` returns `AActor` rather than `AMyBaseActor`.

Comment: And you cannot make getResult return your BaseActor?

Comment: `FHitResult::GetActor()` returns `AActor`. [Doc](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Engine/FHitResult/GetActor/).

Comment: unreal is a engine with a source-available license which lets you modify the engine code, no?

Comment: Yes it is possible but versioning issue comes later. :-)

Comment: in this case you can restrict your changes to just AActor. And you shouldn't be changing engine version mid development anyway, too many issues waiting on that path.